# ORDER BY FROM ANOTHER TABLE

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I am having difficultly ordering a table from another source. I am trying to do something like this;

```
SELECT * FROM tblSomething
ORDER BY ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tblOrderList)
```

Obviously it will not let me do this is there a work around.

Comment: Since `IN` can only produce the results `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`, are those the values by which you intend to sort these results? If not, some more explanation of *how* these two tables interrelate are needed, because `IN` is probably wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a total guess:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblSomething S
ORDER BY CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                          FROM tblOrderList OL
                          WHERE OL.ID = S.ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC;
```

If not, please update your post with sample and expected results.